# ACF user field with custom field attached to user

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I'm using ACF "[user](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/user/)" field to attach a user to a post. The user has a series of custom fields like "short-description".

The code below us able to show the correct *user name* but unable to display the *short-description*. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

```
<?php $user = get_field("seller"); if( $user ): ?>
<h3><?php echo $user['display_name']; ?></h3>
<?php the_field('short-description'); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This code don't work either:

```
<?php the_field('short-description', $user); ?>
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

@CBroe helped me find the solution which is:

```
<?php $user = get_field("seller"); if( $user ): ?>
<h3><?php echo $user['display_name']; ?></h3>
<?php $author_id = get_the_author_meta('ID');?>
<?php the_field('short-description', 'user_'. $author_id);?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: But why is this using the id of the post author now, should this not be the id of your `seller` user?